# I got an error when deploying a scala-play app to Cloud Foundry using Heroku builpack

Tags: scala, heroku, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I got this when I try to run my scala-play app on CloudFoundry, as a builpack I'm using this one form Heroku https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

When I run the app on local it works fine but I can't find the cause of this problem.

What might be the cause? How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: seems like the heroku buildpack expects your app directory to be a git repository? Maybe `git init` will help?

Comment: It looks like but the directory I'm uploading to be executed on CloudFoundry has already a .git subfolder (that was created by git init).

Comment: Ok... Another guess: maybe there is a manifest.yml file in your directory that causes not the entire directory to be uploaded, but just a specific file? Or possibly you push with the --path option?